# Data Model with multiple foreign keys Power Bi

Tags: database, powerbi, foreign-keys, relational-database

Data Modeling issues

Hello everyone!

I've began studying Power Bi for my reports because I think it can be a good entry in my CV and because it could help my team to visualize problems.

I've created the report in Excel and I wanted to give it a shot and "export" it to Power Bi. I've been following a course, but I feel like this data model is too difficult for now (maybe).

So basically I have three tables:

Dimension: Stock Balance

PK = SKU Code

FACT Table 1 = LMC = WHAT WE SENT

Here we have multiple instances of the SKU Code but what is important is the Order + Post (that have been concatenated in PQ).
In this table, there are multiple and unique instances of SKU Codes  and they can have different Order + Post numbers (so item xxx can have more than 10 unique Order + Post numbers).

For one SKU Code I can have the same Order + Post repeated (partial orders, so item xxx can have 10 repeated Order + Post numbers).

FACT Table 2 = CONF = WHAT WE RECEIVE

It is like the LMC table; multiple instances of the SKU codes but here the Order + Post could possibly match, but it doesn't most of the time.

I've tried do a Star schema: Link Stock Balance with both of the tables but when I create a Matrix visualization and organize as follow:

SKU (Stock Balance)

LMC10 (order + Post)

Conf (order + post)

When I add the CONF data, the matrix says it can't load stuff because relationship do not exist (I guess between CONF and LMC).

I thought maybe I can do like the excel report: merge LMC and CONF with a left join and call it a day but I wanted to use it as last resort. My problem is linking LMC and CONF as I do not have 100% uniqueness in these two tables, I can't find a primary key between those. I thought that maybe I could just isolate the partials?

Any tips?

Comment: "I can't find a primary key between those" A primary key applies for a single table, not "between" anything. A primary key typically consists of several columns. You keep those columns separate. So your "have been concatenated in PQ" makes no sense. Please go to any tutorial on database design and learn how to specify tables in full, including key(s). Then amend your question.